# Texture's alpha channel not working when using malloc Scribble in OpenGL ES

Tags: iphone, opengl-es

I made an iPhone game that appears to work well.

However, when I run it with malloc scribble enabled, the alpha channel of my textures is being ignored. Transparent zones appear solid gray.

Any idea? have the same problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This means that your alpha channel was not being properly initialized.  This is commonly seen when you load textures using CGImage, and blit that image into a CGBitmapContext to get the decoded version which by default is a blended blit instead of a copy.  Can you describe how you load those textures?